# SWIFT: In App purchase crashes but displays PaymentSheet. After the first crash, it all works fine

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My ViewDidLoad calls all of the functions for fetchProduct...

This works fine in Sandbox on device when i build from XCode, but when I build to test flight, the app crashes, but the PaymentSheet is displayed over the home screen upon crashing.
Each time the user tries to purchase after the crash, it works fine. But the crash is immediately causing loss of purchases.

```
  
    func fetchProductLove(){
        print("Fetching")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ["LOVEDECK"])
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        
    }
    
    func fetchProductExplicit(){
        print("Fetching")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ["EXPLICITDECK"])
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func fetchProductAll(){
        print("Fetching")
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ["ALLQUESTIONSDECK"])
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let product = response.products.first { //14:30 of IAP by iOSAcademy for multiple products
                self.myProduct = product
                print(product.productIdentifier)
                print(product.localizedTitle)
                print(product.localizedDescription)
                print(product.priceLocale)
                print(product.price)
               
            }
            else {
                print("Couldnt find product")
            }

        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func clickStartGame(_ sender: Any) {
       startLoading()
        if deckIsPurchased == true
        {
            getQuestionsForGame()
        }
        else if deckIsPurchased == false {
          
            if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
         startTransaction()
            }
            else {
                let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Apple ID is unable to make purchases. Contact Apple or info@whostmostapp.com to resolve.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }
    
    
    func startTransaction(){
     
          guard let PurchasingProduct = myProduct else {
           
            print("Did Not Find At All")
            if myProduct == nil {
                let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Unable to Download", message: "The purchase has not been made. Check your connection and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                  endLoading()
            }
            
            return
          }
        
        if myProduct != nil{
              let payment = SKPayment(product: PurchasingProduct)
                print(payment)
              SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
              SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        }
              
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.error ?? "")
            switch transaction.transactionState {
    
            
            case .purchasing:
               
            break
            
            case .purchased, .restored:
                //unlock item
                print("DeckRefName",deckNameRefValue)
                if deckNameRefValue == "LovePotion"{
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "hasPurchasedLovePotionDeck")

                }
                else if deckNameRefValue == "Explicit"{
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "hasPurchasedExplicitDeck")
                }
                else if deckNameRefValue == "All"{
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "hasPurchasedLovePotionDeck")
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "hasPurchasedExplicitDeck")
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Yes", forKey: "hasPurchasedAllDeck")
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
                layoutForCompletedPurchase()
                deckIsPurchased = true
                Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventPurchase, parameters: ["Product": deckNameRefValue, "Price":deckPriceValue])

                endLoading()
                
            break
                
                
                
            case .failed, .deferred:
                //no operation
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
                let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Unable to complete the purchase. Check your network connection and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                endLoading()
            break
            
           default:
                //no operation

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
            
                break
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What is the crash message? Presumably, if you're on TestFlight, you can get crash reports. Without including that, it is pretty speculative.

Comment: Also, from an implementation point of view, you should add your payment queue observer in `didFinishLaunching` and never remove it. If you have uncompleted transactions they will be presented when your application launches. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506042-add

Comment: I needed to look closer into the Test-flight crash reports! - solved

Answer (score 1):

FOUND SOLUTION - I was using a SKPaymentQueue on a different page within the application and it wasnt properly closed